# Can we use the work-energy theorem to find pressure function a liquid in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Can we use the work-energy theorem for a liquid in a container which is accelerated and where the liquid is static with respect to the container to find the pressure at different points? I tried but I didn't get the correct answer, can someone please tell me how we can use the work-energy theorem here?

Comment: By that do you mean Bernoulli?